# Finding an accurate average with the least number of samples

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

For the process I am testing, if I run 1000 trials I get an average score of 84.2 with a standard deviation of 11.35.

So my question is, is it possible to run this less than 1000 times and still get an average that is within +/- 1 score?

Comment: Are the scores normally distributed?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.

Comment: By central limit theorem the average will be normally distributed provided the trials are iid. Your current sample mean has SE 11.35/sqrt(1000) = 0.36. 95% confidence interval is sample mean +/- 1.96×SE, ie +/- 0.70. There is no guarantee that you are within a range of the score but 95% of CIs calculated will contain true mean. For a 95% CI that is +/- 1 you need SE=0.51 so N=495 should do it (although you might also get variation in measured SD).

Comment: There are versions of CLT whch apply whether or not you have independence or identical distributions (under some restrictions), but the problem is there's not really a basis given here bby which to assert that $n=1000$ is the same thing as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @tristan Please post that as an answer so that people can vote and comment on it.  You did a very nice job in providing the answer as well as interpreting it and explaining the underlying assumptions in a very pithy manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As encouraged by @whuber I am re-posting my comment as an answer.

By central limit theorem the average will be approximately normally distributed provided the trials are iid. Your current sample mean has $SE=11.35/\sqrt{1000} = 0.36$. 95% confidence interval is sample mean $\pm 1.96\times SE$, ie $\pm 0.70$. (95% of normal distribution is within $1.96 \sigma$ of mean)

There is no guarantee that you are within a range of the score but 95% of CIs calculated will contain true mean.

For a 95% CI that is $\pm 1$ you need $SE=0.51$ so $N=495$ should do it (although you might also get variation in measured SD).

More detailed calculations (since my original comment was long on brevity):

\begin{align}
1.96 \times SE = 1.96 \times \frac{SD}{\sqrt{N}} &= 1 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} &= \frac{1}{1.96 \times SD} \\
\sqrt{N} &= 1.96 \times SD \\
N &= (1.96\times SD)^2 \\
&= 494.9
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) To head off the potential for some negative comments, you might find it useful to insert "approximately" before "normally distributed."  As a practical matter you can't say much more than you have, given the limited information, but it's a good idea to warn people that there are circumstances in which the Normal approximation will not be a good one. If you feel like it, you might also want to react to the use of "process" in the question by making some remarks about the potential for serial correlation to ruin the approximation, too.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your helpful tips. Indeed if it is a process it could violate the iid assumption. If the questioner would like to tell us a bit more I'm sure you will be more than capable of helping if needed :)